# How to make google map NOT centered, but a little bit above?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created function, which is centering me google map, but I need to make it a little bit above, because me description window is not visible.

This is picture how it looks:

[image]

And this is picture how I want to look:

[image]

Here is a js script.

```
   var address = "{{$restaurant->address}}";
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
     var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 17,
       scrollwheel: false,
       styles: styleArray,
       center: latlng
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });

     var contentString = "<b style='color:black'>{{$restaurant->address}}</b>"; // HTML text to display in the InfoWindow
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { content: contentString } );
     infowindow.open( map, marker );
     google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() { infowindow.open( map, marker ); });

     var center;
     function calculateCenter() {
      center = map.getCenter();
     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
      calculateCenter();
     });

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
      map.setCenter(center);
     });

  }else {
       alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

Comment: I've never really used the Google Maps API, but can't you just bump the location used in the call to map.setCenter? Add a small offset like 0.00001, might just do the trick?

Comment: @ChristiaanRakowski: You may want to calculate the offset from map viewport size and zoom level, but in essence, you're right. (I haven't touched the GMaps API too much since v2, so I'm not making this an answer, as it's not specific enough; but the same principle applies to any mapping platform.)

Comment: just tried with static latlang , may be because of that it's happening.not sure but we can try it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a helper function that centers the map based on the location of the marker and the dimensions of the info window (as far as I know).

If your `infoWindow` has fixed dimensions, using the `panBy` method is probably the easiest way to implement what you need.

From [the API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference):

> `panBy(x:number, y:number)`
>
> Changes the center of the map by the given distance in pixels. If the distance is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated. Note that the map coordinate system increases from west to east (for x values) and north to south (for y values).

A simple example:

```
// Use the property `center` to define the initial center of the map
var mapOptions = {};

// Render the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

// Transition the center of the map by 0 pixels to the east, 
// and n pixels to the south, where n is half the height of
// the infoWindow
map.panBy(0, n);
```

If the `infoWindow` has dynamic dimensions, you'll have to query its dimensions first and then use the `panBy` method.

Would this work for you?